# Disable "other people are logged on to this computer" popup on XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I've a small PC connected to the TV in the living room, used as a sort of a media appliance, running Windows XP. Sometimes, I play Internet radio on it with WinAMP. While it's playing radio, sometimes I'd like to shut down the machine without interacting with the screen and keyboard, just by pressing the power button on the computer case.

However, if I do that, I get a popup saying "other people are logged on to this computer" blah blah. Is there a way to get rid of that popup? I hate to turn on the TV just to shut down the computer.

Comment: @Farseeker While it works, I wouldn't recommend that because Windows isn't designed to be shut down that way. There are shutdown services and OS cleanup to be done, and it might cause corruption or damage to data if things aren't properly closed down.

Comment: @sidran - I know, it was meant to be slightly humerous, whilst also a valid answer. Hence why I didn't post it as an "answer"

Comment: @Farseeker I know, but I just wanted to clarify for those that didn't catch on. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a shortcut and have the location as:

```
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -s -f -t 0
```

This forces shutdown of the machine, I'm not sure if it'll fix your problem but give it a try.

EDIT::

Try [Shutdown Timer](http://sinvise.net/software/shutdown-timer)

Comment: A shortcut requires interaction with the keyboard/mouse to execute it, which the OP is trying to avoid (otherwise, he could just click the OK button)